# Solve for a with solution

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving, lambert-w

Can somebody provide me the detailed solution for

$$\log_{2021}a=2022-a$$

I know the answer is $2021$ but don't know, the solution.

(got $2021$ by trial and error method)

Comment: perhaps include where this question come from and also is there a specification of if $a$ is an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

> \begin{align}\log_{2021}a=2022-a \tag{1}\label{1}\end{align}

Consider an equivalent equation

\begin{align}
\ln_b(a)=
\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)} 
&= c-a
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}
where $b=2021$, $c=2022$.

It is well-known that \eqref{2} is solvable in terms of the [Lambert $\W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function),
so, we need to transform \eqref{2} to the form $u(a)\exp(u(a))=v$,
where $u(a)$ is some function of the unknown $a$ and $v$ is some constant
in terms of $b$ and $c$.

\begin{align}
\ln(a)
&= c\ln(b)-a\ln(b)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
a
&= \exp(c\ln(b)-a\ln(b))
\\
&=\exp(c\ln(b))\exp(-a\ln(b))
\\
&=b^c\exp(-a\ln(b))
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a\exp(a\ln(b))
&=
b^c
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\ln(b)a\exp(a\ln(b))
&=
\ln(b)b^c
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Now we have \eqref{6} in the desired form $u(a)\exp(u(a))=v$
where $u(a)=\ln(b)a$, $v=\ln(b)b^c$, so we can apply the Lambert $\W$ function
to both sides of \eqref{6} and simplify:

\begin{align}
\W\left(\ln(b)a\exp(a\ln(b))\right)
&=
\W\left(\ln(b)b^c\right)
\tag{7}\label{7}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\ln(b)a
&=
\W\left(\ln(b)b^c\right)
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
a
&=
\frac{\W\left(\ln(b)b^c\right)}{\ln(b)}
\tag{9}\label{9}
.
\end{align}

For given values of $b$ and $c$ the argument of $\W$ in \eqref{9} is positive,
hence there is only one real solution of \eqref{9} as well as the original \eqref{1}.

Since $c=b+1$ in the original equation, \eqref{9} can be further simplified as follows:

\begin{align}
a
&=
\frac{\W\left(\ln(b)b^{b+1}\right)}{\ln(b)}
\tag{10}\label{10}
,\\
a
&=
\frac{\W\left(b\ln(b)b^b\right)}{\ln(b)}
=
\frac{\W\left(\ln(b^b)b^b\right)}{\ln(b)}
=
\frac{\W\left(\ln(b^b)\exp\left(\ln(b^b)\right)\right)}{\ln(b)}
\tag{11}\label{11}
,\\
a&=
\frac{\ln(b^b)}{\ln(b)}
=
\frac{b\ln(b)}{\ln(b)}
=b=2021
\tag{12}\label{12}
.
\end{align}

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side is (strictly) monotonically increasing in $a$.  The right-hand side is (strictly) monotonically decreasing in $a$.  So if there is a solution, there is only one.

Basic log property:  When $a = 1$, the left-hand side is $0$ and the right-hand side is positive.

$x$-intercept: When $a = 2022$, the right-hand side is $0$ and the left-hand side is positive (very slightly larger than one).  Having swapped which side is the larger, the unique solution has $1 < a < 2022$.

On that interval, the left-hand side is never as large as $2$.  For the right-hand side to be less than $2$, $a> 2020$, so $2020 < a < 2022$.

Clearly, it's time to bisect.  Try $a = 2021$ to determine whether the left-hand side or right-hand side is the larger (to find out which half of the interval to continue searching -- i.e. to find out if the left-hand side is slightly less than $1$ or slightly greater than $1$ at the solution).  As a lucky accident, we find that $a = 2021$ is the solution.

Comment: *"The left-hand side is (strictly) monotonically increasing in a. The right-hand side is (strictly) monotonically decreasing in a. So if there is a solution, there is only one."* Do you mean that, monotonicity is sufficient (we could use the same reasoning if they were only monotonically increasing/decreasing), but in this case they happened to also be strictly increasing/decreasing?

Comment: @JamesA : Non-strict monotonicity permits an arbitrarily large number of solutions.  For example $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lceil -x \rceil$.  I parenthesize "strictly" because some writers define "monotonic" to be a synonym for "strictly monotonic" and some do not.